# What code do I type in next page after passing gridview button clicked rowindex

Tags: asp.net

I pass the  row index value into next page when gridview button clicked using this code

```
if(e.CommandName=="select")
{
      int Id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
      //Label1.Text = Id.ToString();
       Response.Redirect("~/manclothes1.aspx?Id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());

}
```

but i don't know what code i write in next page to display row data
please can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you don't actually pass code to a new page.  Instead you modify the controls on the current page and the ASP.NET framework re-renders the page for you.  Instead of the Response.Redirect line you want something like

```
 DataGrid1.EditItemIndex = Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page_load of manclothes1.aspx you can try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
    {
         var id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
         // do something with id variable
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to reference whatever code on the current page populates the gridview with data in the first place.  Essentially, where the code on the current page gets many rows to populate a gridview, the code on the `manclothes1.aspx` page will get one row.  If it's data from a database, the query will likely be very much the same but with an additional `WHERE` clause to filter by (I'm assuming) an ID value, which is probably a primary key (or *the* primary key, if we're talking about only one table).

To put this into context, what the call to `Response.Redirect()` is doing is telling the client (browser) to issue an entirely new request (a `GET` request, that is) for an entirely new resource (`manclothes.aspx` with a query string parameter).  So understand that "the next page" knows *nothing* of the gridview on the current page.  Nor should it, really.  The request should be handled entirely separate from the current page.